# How can one filter by an AdWord campaign's "Product Group " with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I've been tasked with creating custom reports and dashboards in Google Analytics to better illustrate our ongoing AdWords campaigns. For some of these reports/dashboards, I need to reach a better level of definition than "Ad Group". Specifically, I need to be able to report/filter at the "Product Group" level.

(For example, I've been asked to create a create an exportable report within Analytics that provides the comparative revenue, ROI, etc. of different Product Groups within a particularly important Ad Group.)

However, I can't seem to find a way to filter or isolate by Product Group within Analytics. "Campaign" and "Ad Group" seem to be the best definitions available. Is there a way to filter by "Product Group"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Analytics interface:

```
Acquisition -> Adwords -> Shopping Campaigns -> Shopping Product Type Level 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I can't find the trail you've posted. The main "Reporting" tab has "Acquisitions -> Campaigns", but no relevant "product type" options. In "Edit Custom Report", the only options under Acquisitions are as follows: Default Channel Grouping, Medium, Referral Path, Source, Source/Medium, and Traffic Type.

Comment: Whoops, missed a step. That's what I get doing it from memory. If you link your Adwords Account it's under Acquisitions -> Adwords. Edited the post to add this in.

Comment: Thank you, Yhorian!

For collective clarity, the trail is **"Analytics Reporting Tab" -> "Acquisition" -> "AdWords" -> "Shopping Campaigns" -> set "Primary Dimension" to "Shopping Product Type Level 1"**.